# If a regression is fit without an intercept, why are the fitted values a linear function of the response?

Tags: regression, machine-learning

Consider the model $y_i = \beta x_i + \varepsilon_i$ (simple linear regression without an intercept).

In this setting, the $i$th fitted value is

$$\hat{y}_i = \hat{\beta}x_i$$

Where

$$\hat{\beta} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i y_i}{\sum_{i'=1}^n x_{i'}^2}$$

I am being asked to find an expression for $\alpha_{i'}$ such that we can write

$$\hat{y}_i = \sum_{i'=1}^n \alpha_{i'} y_{i'}$$

That is, the fitted values are linear combinations of $y_{i'}$.

---

Aside from finding $\alpha_{i'}$, I am confused as to why the index changes to $i'$ in the denominator of $\hat{\beta}$. What's the point in doing this and what is $\alpha_{i'}$?

For reference, this is exercise 5 from chapter 3 of [an Introduction to Statistical Learning](https://hastie.su.domains/ISLR2/ISLRv2_website.pdf).

> Consider the fitted values that result from performing linear regression without an intercept. In this setting, the ith fitted value takes the form
> $$\hat{y}_i = x_i \hat{\beta}$$
> where
> $$\hat{\beta} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i y_i}{\sum_{i'=1}^n x_{i'}^2}$$
> Show that we can write
> $$\hat{y}_i = \sum_{i'=1}^n \alpha_{i'}y_{i'}$$
> What is $\alpha_{i'}$?
>
> *Note: We interpret this result by saying that the fitted values from
> linear regression are linear combinations of the response values.*

Comment: Does $(X^TX)^{-1} X^Ty$ look familiar to you?

Comment: There is no mathematical reason to use the symbol "$i^\prime$" in the summation.  Some authors do this to avoid any possibility of confusing this "bound variable" with the symbol "$i$" employed in the sum in the numerator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I stared at the question long enough. Turns out it's just a matter of playing around with the summation's indices.

If we substitute $\hat{\beta}$ into $\hat{y}_i$
$$\hat{y}_i = x_i \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i y_i}{\sum_{i'=1}^n x_{i'}^2}$$

For the purpose of both summations, the $x_i$ on the left is a constant. Hence, if we change the indices to match the question
\begin{align}
\hat{y}_i & = x_i \frac{\sum_{i'=1}^n x_{i'} y_{i'}}{\sum_{j=1}^n x_j^2} \\
& = \frac{\sum_{i'=1}^n x_ix_{i'} y_{i'}}{\sum_{j=1}^n x_j^2} \\
& = \sum_{i'=1}^n \frac{x_i x_{i'}}{\sum_{j=1}^n x_j^2} y_{i'} \\
& = \sum_{i'=1}^n \alpha_{i'} y_{i'}
\end{align}

Where
$$\alpha_{i'} = \frac{x_i x_{i'}}{\sum_{j=1}^n x_j^2}$$